# How does sethbling "steal items from air" in this video?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

Around 0:40, sethbling throws iron blocks at the huge villager statue, and they vanish. How does that work? And what version of Minecraft do I need to use to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way would be a teleport command such as:

```
/tp @e[type=Item,x=X1,y=Y1,z=Z1,r=10] X2 Y2 Z2
```

Replace "X1", "Y1" and "Z1" with the coordinates where you want the items to be "stolen" from, and "X2", "Y2" and "Z2" with where you want the items to be moved to. You can also change the "10" to increase or decrease the radius from the point that things are stolen from.

This requires a minimum of snapshot 14w02a.

Comment: `/kill @e[type=Item]`

Comment: but now how will i test to verify the item was there? @colorfusion

Comment: @DatEpicCoderGuyWhoPrograms ^

Comment: @dan14941 Use the "/testfor" command after having teleported the item. This command should work:  

   /testfor @e[type=Item,x=X2,y=Y2,z=Z2,r=1] {Item:{id:"minecraft:stone"}}     Obviously change the coordinates and item ID to whatever you want to test for.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use this command.

```
/kill @e[type=Item]
```

This kills all entities that are items. You can add more parameters such as `r` to specify the radius in which all items are killed.